# JSF Storing data into a cookie

Tags: jsf, cookies

I want to store some user data into a cookie so it's always there when they load the web app, even if the session has expired.

What's the best way of doing this with JSF?

Comment: Cookies may be the wrong approach here. Cookies are for communication from the client to the server. If you want client-side storage, you should maybe look at DOM Storage.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Writing to a cookie:**

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
 .getExternalContext()
 .addResponseCookie("CookieName", "value", null);
```

**Reading the cookie**

```
Map<String, Object> requestCookieMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .getExternalContext()
   .getRequestCookieMap();
```

Comment: If you're planning on adding properties, you could also use "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse()", cast it to HttpServletResponse, and then use "resp.addCookie(Cookie c)".

Comment: I'm using JSF2.2 and this answer didn't work. If you had the same issue try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934016/how-to-add-cookie-in-jsf